# Apply attributes on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this working code which updates attributes based on the selection from a drop down box. I have it so the input fields and drop down save but currently the attributes do not. So when I refresh the page all of the data is still their but the input fields are no longer set to disabled. What would be the best way to go about that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my_option').on('change', change_attribute);
});

function change_attribute() {
  var version_val = $(this).val();
  var parent_row = $(this).closest('tr');


  if (version_val == 10) {
    parent_row.find('.1').find('input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    parent_row.find('.2').find('input').removeAttr("disabled");

  } else if (version_val == 20) {
    parent_row.find('.2').find('input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    parent_row.find('.1').find('input').removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="my_option">
          <option>10</option>
          <option>20</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="1"><input type="text"></td>
      <td class="2"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="my_option">
          <option>10</option>
          <option>20</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="1"><input type="text"></td>
      <td class="2"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="my_option">
          <option>10</option>
          <option>20</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="1"><input type="text"></td>
      <td class="2"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use cookies or localStorage to save the data

Comment: Use a database to store the selected dropdown menu items or store them in the browser's local storage.

Comment: Do you want to trigger the `change_attribute` on page load? then use `$('.my_option').on('change', change_attribute).trigger("change");`

Comment: If the values are saved, then you just need to trigger a change event when the page loads: `.trigger('change')`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Rory/Carsten's response is what I was looking for.